# Merge databases like time series in R

Tags: database, r, merge, time-series

Given the databases

```
> x
     Date         Values_X Names_X
[1,] "01.01.2012" "1"      "A"    
[2,] "02.01.2012" "2"      "B"    
[3,] "01.02.2012" "3"      "C"
```

and

```
> y
     Date         Values_Y Colors_Y
[1,] "01.01.2012" "1"      "red"    
[2,] "02.01.2012" "2"      "green"    
[3,] "01.03.2012" "3"      "blue"
```

I would like to merge them into the database `z`

```
 Date           Values_X Names_X  Values_Y Colors_Y
[1,] "01.01.2012" "1"      "A"     "1"      "red"    
[2,] "02.01.2012" "2"      "B"     "2"      "green"   
[3,] "01.02.2012" "3"      "C"     NA         NA
[4,] "01.03.2012" NA       NA      "3"      "blue"
```

considering the columns of both `x` and `y` as time series and merging them w.r.t. the common column `Date`. `NA`'s should be produced in case of missing entries.

I am aware of the `merge` function for time series in R; unfortunately I have not been able to apply it successfully to databases so far. Any hint?

Comment: Did you try `merge(x, y, by = "Date", all = TRUE)`?

Comment: I tried it right now and it works: thank you very much. Please, convert your comment into an answer: I would gladly upvote and flag it.

Comment: Why would you flag it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do should be

```
merge(x, y, by = "Date", all = TRUE)
```

Perhaps you forgot to use `all = TRUE` in which case some observations would have been dropped (check out `?merge` for more information about it)